# Container Using std::set with Multiple Compare Criteria

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl

I'm trying to write a container comprising of two `std::set`s with identical elements using different comparator classes. Here's my take, simplified:

```
struct Element
{
    // foo and bar are immutable to prevent messing set order up.
    FooStruct const foo;
    BarStruct const bar;
    int someVar;

    Element(FooStruct foo);
    Element(BarStruct bar);
};

class CriterionFoo
{
    // Sorts according to member foo.
    bool operator()(Element* const& arg0, Element* const& arg1);
};

class CriterionBar
{
    // Sorts according to member bar.
    bool operator()(Element* const& arg0, Element* const& arg1);
};

class ElementContainer
{
    typedef std::set<Element*, CriterionFoo> FooSortedSet;
    typedef std::set<Element*, CriterionBar> BarSortedSet;

    FooSortedSet fooSortedSet;
    BarSortedSet barSortedSet;

    // fooSortedSet.find(&Element(myFoo))
    Element* findElement(FooStruct myFoo);
    // barSortedSet.find(&Element(myBar))
    Element* findElement(BarStruct myBar);

    // Inserts in both sets.
    void insert(Element* element);

    // Enter total alienation and existential crisis...
    void erase(BarStruct myBar);
    void erase(FooStruct myFoo);
};
```

All I wanted to achieve was to make a set wrapper that finds in log(n) complexity a member with two different search criteria. `ElementContainer::erase` method can easily find the `[Foo|Bar]SortedSet::iterator` for either criterion, but I'll have to traverse the other one naïvely anyway (which pretty much beats the whole point). Then again, I can put `[Foo|Bar]SortedSet::const_iterator` references inside `Element` struct and reach the corresponding iterator in the other set with a single step, but this feels like an overkill.

OK now, I can't possibly be the first person to ever encounter this. Is there any established way of keeping a set of elements with easy navigation using more than a single criteria? Particularly without going on an over-engineering frenzy?

Comment: have a look at boost multi-index: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html

Comment: *"I'll have to traverse the other one naïvely"*, retrieve element before removal, so you get both `Foo` and `Bar` member for log(n) search...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you want heterogeneous lookup: The ability to find the `Element` with a given `BarStruct` value `myBar` *without* having to construct a dummy `Element(myBar)`. This can be achieved by adding the following `operator()` overloads to `CriterionBar` (and equivalently `CriterionFoo`):

```
bool operator()(Element* const& lhs, BarStruct const& rhs) const;
bool operator()(BarStruct const& lhs, Element* const& rhs) const;
```

*Note: Your comparison operators must be `const` member functions!*

Further, you [need to add](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/06/09/search-set-another-type-key/) an `is_transparent` to make the set consider these additional comparison options (and add the corresponding overloads to e.g. `find`). For example:

```
using is_transparent = void;
```

This is not strictly necessary, but miles better than the dummy `Element` thing you are doing currently.

The actual steps for deleting from both sets in two `O(log(N))` operations are simple:

```
void erase(FooStruct myFoo)
{
  auto fooIt = fooSortedSet.find(myFoo);
  Element* elementToErase = *fooIt;
  auto barIt = barSortedSet.find(elementToErase);

  fooSortedSet.erase(fooIt);
  barSortedSet.erase(barIt);
}
```

Comment: Nice operator overload trick, I'll take that into consideration. Neither of the sets take `Element*` type as their key value though, I don't get how I can `find` using that reference.

Edit: You might have a point there, I think I need to think this over with a clear head.

Comment: @corsel Mind the edits I made since. In particular, `is_transparent` is required for it to work.

Comment: @corsel What do you mean "the sets don't take `Element*` as key value"? You can compare/distinguish/find elements, that's the point of a set...

Comment: Yeah it was a moment of confusion :) I guess I can mark this as an answer. Seems so obvious after it's answered.